# How to use a return value in another function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm self-teaching myself JavaScript and out of curiosity I'm wondering what is the proper way of returning a value from one function to be used in another function. For example:

```
function firstFunction() {
  // do something;
  return somevalue 
}
```

So how do I set up the second function to use somevalue? Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Call the function and save the return value of that very call.

```
function firstFunction() {
  // do something
  return "testing 123";
}

var test = firstFunction();  // this will grab you the return value from firstFunction();
alert(test);
```

You can make this call from another function too, as long as both functions have same **[scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)**.

For example:

```
function testCase() {
  var test = firstFunction(); 
  alert(test);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fp6Gx/)**

Comment: Why not just `alert(firstFunction())`?  I only ask because I marked somebody's question today as a duplicate of this one, but one of the answers there was essentially in the form I give, no intermediate variable required (or `secondFunction(firstFunction)` since `secondFunction`, a non-built-in, is mentioned in another answer)

Comment: That will obviously be better but note that when the question was asked the OP was a beginner and i find it better to teach beginners very basic clear concepts. Saving a return val in a variable makes sense to a beginner

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer, wasn't trying to stir anything up.  I guess one other reason for your approach is it can make debugging easier

Comment: In java we used to mention the data type near the signature doesn't required in JavaScript? Even thought we return the value in same class or in different class?

Answer (score 3):

You could call `firstFunction` from `secondFunction` :

```
function secondFunction() {
    alert(firstFunction());
}
```

Or use a global variable to host the result of `firstFunction` :

```
var v = firstFunction();
function secondFunction() { alert(v); }
```

Or pass the result of `firstFunction` as a parameter to `secondFunction` :

```
function secondFunction(v) { alert(v); }
secondFunction(firstFunction());
```

Or pass `firstFunction` as a parameter to `secondFunction` :

```
function secondFunction(fn) { alert(fn()); }
secondFunction(firstFunction);
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/RK6X7/.

Answer (score 0):

Call function within other function :

```
function abc(){    
    var a = firstFunction();    
}

function firstFunction() {
    Do something;
    return somevalue 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for sure. Have a look below

```
function fnOne(){
  // do something
  return value;
}


function fnTwo(){
 var strVal= fnOne();
//use strValhere   
 alert(strVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var captcha = '';
//function name one
function one(captcha){
var captcha = captcha;
//call another function and pass variable data
var captcha = firstFunction(captcha); 
};
// second function name
function firstFunction(captcha){
alert(captcha);
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function reSult(num1,num2){
    
    if(num1<=num2){
        
        return num1 + num2
    }
    else
    {
        
        return num1 -num2
    }
}



let pass= reSult(40,5);



function outPut(pass,num3){
    if(pass<=40){
        return pass * num3 
    }
    else{
        return pass / num3
    }

}
console.log(outPut(pass,20))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To copy the return value of any javascript(in chrome console), we can use inbuilt `copy()` method.

you can use any expression, function, etc
find some examples below

1. using expresseion

> a = 245;
> copy(a);

2. using function

> ```
> a = function() {
>   return "Hello world!"
> }
> copy(a());
> ```

[Official Doc](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#copyobject) for reference

Comment: Just from your source: "Warning: These functions only work when you call them from the Chrome DevTools Console. They won't work if you try to call them in your scripts."

Comment: Yes, it'll work only in chrome console.