# Callback function seems to be firing before parent function completes

Tags: javascript, callback

I've been teaching myself JS and cannot get this script to work. It is on a SharePoint site, if that matters. According to what I've learned here: https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced
and here: [How to use a return value in another function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674992/how-to-use-a-return-value-in-another-function-in-javascript), it seems like it should. I want to trigger updateListItem() after getUserInfo() has completely finished.

```
function getUserInfo(callbackUI, par1, par2, par3, par4, par5, par6) {
    var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;
    var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.user = context.get_web().ensureUser(users[0].Key);
    context.load(this.user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
         Function.createDelegate(null, ensureUserSuccess), 
         Function.createDelegate(null, onFail)
    );
    callbackUI(par1, par2, par3, par4, par5, par6);  
}

function ensureUserSuccess() {
    var testone = (this.user.get_id());
    $('#userId').html(this.user.get_id());
    console.log(testone);
    return this.user.get_id();
}

function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Query failed. Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

The click event below works, but it's not recognizing the value of 'usersID' (set in ensureUserSuccess()), even though the value is correct in my HTML.

```
$("body").on("click",".savePartner",function(){
    var thisID  = $(this).closest(".singleItemWrap").find(".bigID").text();
    var usersID = $(this).closest(".singleItemWrap").find("#userId").val();

    var itemProperties = {'ITContactId': usersID};
    getUserInfo(updateListItem,_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'GFSTechIntake',thisID,itemProperties,printInfo,logError);


    //updateListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'GFSTechIntake',thisID,itemProperties,printInfo,logError);
    function printInfo()
    {
        console.log('PARTNER UPDATED!');
      //  alert("This item has been assigned!");
    }
    function logError(error){
        alert("An error occurred. Please refresh and try again.");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }

});
```

I've spent hours trying different things I find online but can't seem to get this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an asynchronous function next to another and expect the first one to wait for the other, in this case that's `executeQueryAsync()` and `callbackUI()`, put the one you want executed last the callback of the first:

```
function getUserInfo(callbackUI, par1, par2, par3, par4, par5, par6) {
    var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;
    var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.user = context.get_web().ensureUser(users[0].Key);
    context.load(this.user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
         () => {
             Function.createDelegate(null, ensureUserSuccess);
             callbackUI(par1, par2, par3, par4, par5, par6);
         }, 
         Function.createDelegate(null, onFail)
    );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I plugged in your code and attempted to console log my '$("#userId").val()'  in my updateListItem function, since it should be set by the time this is called, but it is still coming up blank. Any ideas on where I may be going wrong?